# web api 2 custom model binder for nested class.

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I am working on MVC5 web api 2. I met a question regarding to custom model binder. 
I created a custom model binder to resolve ClassA in a ApiController. Then, I was using [ModelBinder(typeof(CustomBinder))] to indicate which action to use model binder. The questions are listed below

1. is there any better way to apply model binder, instead of using [ModelBinder(typeof(CustomBinder))]?
2. if there is ClassX contains a property with ClassA, how can i reuse this CustomBinder? do i need to create a separate modelbinder for ClassX?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no better way. You can do it in the action parameters but is less general.

And you need not do anything at all: the property will be deserialized using the same model binder without extra configuration.

NOTE: you need also to register the custom binder in the Web API configuration.

For more information, please, see the section of Model binders in the [Web API parameter bindign docs](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).